# Fetch Post request not working in Custom functions Office Addin [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I having been facing this error in custom functions excel Add-in, where I'm trying to call an external service inside a custom function. It works fine for a GET request such as this:

```
function stockPrice(ticker) {
var url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + ticker + "/price";
return fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(text) {
        return parseFloat(text);
    });
}

CustomFunctionMappings.STOCKPRICE = stockPrice;
```

Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-tutorial-custom-functions#create-a-custom-function-that-requests-data-from-the-web

But gives an exception for a POST request like this:

```
function stockPrice(ticker) {
var url = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment";
return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body))
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.somevalue;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.error("Caught exception");
        return JSON.stringify(e);
     });
}
```

The above is just a sample to have an idea, of how I'm calling my service. I have tried it with 2-3 different services, and I figured out that after running fetch, the code goes to catch block, and the error value that is returned in the excel is an empty object '{}'. Since there are no ways to debug custom functions on windows, and since there is no specific error description, I'm unable to figure out the issue. I have also added my service domain to App Domain list in manifest file but still no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that particular API accepts POST requests, so you maybe running into that.

Debugging in Windows is still being worked on but you can use Excel online and F12tools to debug.

If you are on Windows, you can console.log statements in conjunction with the Runtime logging:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-best-practices#troubleshooting

Hope that helps and we will update this when debugging is ready on for custom functions on windows desktop.

Comment: I have edited the question with the original request, and I tried to debug using Runtime Logging, and this is the error I'm getting: [TypeError: Network request failed]. Can you please explain why I'm getting this issue, when I can run the same service successfully from other parts of the add-in, but only getting this error in case of custom functions.

Comment: You're code above has an error, i.e. missing a curly brace here;  body: JSON.stringify(body)).

Comment: Checking with the team.Besides the code, there is a single origin policy placed on requests made from the custom functions runtime. So to workaround it, you may need to move the logic to call the Cognitive Service API to server side https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-runtime#requesting-external-data

Comment: Please do not mind the braces mistake, it just happened while copying, sorry! 

About the same origin policy, that you mentioned. Does it not effect the GET requests? cause I'm able to call the GET requests successfully from the custom functions for services running on servers with different origins!

Comment: I'd check out this topic for more info on the same origin policy and CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy. It likely depends on the API provider's access policy.